# Projection from $SO^+(1,4)$ into $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry, conformal-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

### This question is related with the projective light cone model of the conformal geometry of $\mathbb{S}^3$.

Let me denote the Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}_1^5$ as $\mathbb{R}^5$ equipped with a Lorentzian metric
$$<x,y>=-x_0y_0+x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4=x^tI_{1,4}y,$$
where $I_{1,4}=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1,1)$.

Let $\mathcal{C}_+^4$ be the forward light cone of $\mathbb{R}_1^5$, i.e. for any $x\in\mathcal{C}_+^4$, we have that $x_0>0$. One can see that the projective light cone
$$\mathcal{Q}^3=\left\{\left[x\right]\in\mathbb{R}P^4|x\in\mathcal{C}_+^4\right\},$$
with the induced conformal metric, is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^3$, and the conformal group of $\mathcal{Q}^3$ is exactly the orthogonal group $O(1,4)/\{\pm 1\}$ of $\mathbb{R}_1^5$, acting on $\mathcal{Q}^3$ by $T(\left[x\right])=\left[Tx\right]$, for $T\in O(1,4)$.

Denote by $SO^+(1,4)$ the connected component of $O(1,4)$ containing $I$, that is for any $T\in SO^+(1,4)$ we have that $\det T=1$ and $T$ preserves the signature of the first coordinate of any $x\in\mathbb{R}_1^5$ (i.e., preserves the time direction).

---

Does anyone know an explicit expression for the projection that arises after this construction, say $\pi:SO^+(1,4)\to\mathbb{S}^3$? Or any idea on how to derive it?

Or, in case not, any reference to consult for this topic?

I am also interested in the projection $\pi^\prime:SO^+(1,4)\to\mathbb{R}^3$, which I can construct if I know the previous one or the other way around, so if this one is known by anyone this is also really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that each null line in $\mathcal Q$ intersects the reference plane $\Pi := \{x_0 = 1\}$ in precisely one point, so that $\mathcal Q \cap \Pi \cong \Bbb S^3$: The points $p = (1, r)$ in this intersection are precisely those that satisfy $0 = \langle (1, r) , (1, r) \rangle = -1 + || r ||^2 ,$ that is, $$||r||^2 = 1$$ (here, $||\cdot||$ is the usual Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^4 \cong \Pi$).

Now, pick a reference line $\ell_0 \in \mathcal Q$, which we can write as $[ p_0 ]$ for some unique $p_0 = (1, r_0) \in \mathcal Q \cap \Pi$. Then, $A \in \textrm{SO}^+(1, 4)$ maps $\ell_0$ to
$$A \cdot \ell_0 = [ A \cdot p_0] ,$$
and scaling $A \cdot p_0$ by the reciprocal of its first entry gives us a point in $\mathcal Q \cap \Pi$.

A little more explicitly, with respect to the basis used to define the bilinear form, given an element $$A = \pmatrix{\lambda & y^{\top} \\ x & B} \in \textrm{SO}(1, 4),$$ we have
$$A \cdot p_0 = \pmatrix{\lambda & y^{\top} \\ x & B} \pmatrix{1\\r_0} = \pmatrix{\lambda + y^{\top} r_0 \\ x + B r_0} . $$ Then, the intersection of the line $[A \cdot p]$ with $\Pi$ is some $(1, r')$, and solving for $r'$ gives the explicit map $\textrm{SO}(1, 4) \to \Bbb S^3$:
$$A = \pmatrix{\lambda & y^{\top} \\ x & B} \mapsto (\lambda + y^{\top} r_0)^{-1} (x + B r_0) = \frac{x + B r_0}{||x + B r_0||}.$$
We can make this more explicit but less symmetric by picking a convenient explicit point $r_0$. (We can also use the fact that $A$ preserves the bilinear form to write $y$ in terms of $A$, $x$, $\lambda$.)

I do not know which map is meant by $\pi' : \textrm{SO}^+(1, 4) \to \Bbb R^3$. (That said, the differential of the map $\pi$ is a map $\mathfrak{so}(1, 4) \to T_{r_0} \Bbb S^3$, and if we take $r_0$ to be a canonical basis vector, we get a more-or-less canonical identification $T_{r_0} \Bbb S^3 \leftrightarrow \Bbb R^3$.)

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I guess that you mistyped "$\langle p_0 \rangle$", "$\langle A\cdot p_0 \rangle$" and "$\langle A\cdot p \rangle$". These don't make sense to me, as I would write "$\left[ p_0 \right]$", "$\left[ A\cdot p_0 \right]$" and "$\left[ A\cdot p \right]$" since these are lines... am I right? Also, how do you get the equality $(\lambda + y^{\top} r_0)^{-1} (x + B r_0) = \frac{x + B r_0}{||x + B r_0||}$? It seems totally obscure to me this claim. By $\pi' : \textrm{SO}^+(1, 4) \to \mathbb R^3$ I just meant $\pi_s\circ\pi$, with $\pi_s$ the stereographic projection.

Comment: By $\langle u \rangle$ I just mean the span of $u$, what you call $[u]$. I'll edit my answer to match the notation in your question. The equality is just a consequence of the fact that the vector must be the unit normalization of a vector in the direction of the vector $x + B r_0$.

Comment: (As an aside, one might well prefer the first expression, $(\lambda + y^{\top} r_0)^{-1}(x + B r_0)$ because it makes clear that the components are rational functions of the entries of $A$.)

Comment: I tried an example in MATLAB and for some reason the result is not in $\mathbb{S}^3$. Is there any constraint in the choice of $r_0\in\mathbb{S}^3$? I took $r_0=(1,0,0,0)$ and $$A=\pmatrix{{9\over 8}-{e^{iz}\over 16}-{e^{-iz}\over 16} & {3\over 16}e^{-iz}(e^{iz}-1)^2 & {\sqrt{2}\over 4}\sin{z} & 0 & 0\\ -{3\over 16}e^{-iz}(e^{iz}-1)^2 & {9\over 16}e^{-iz}+{9\over 16}e^{iz}-{1\over 8} & {3\sqrt{2}\over 4}\sin{z} & 0 & 0\\ {\sqrt{2}\over 4}\sin{z} & -{3\sqrt{2}\over 4}\sin{z} & \cos{z} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cos{z} & \sin{z}\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sin{z} & \cos{z}}\in\mathrm{SO}^+(1,4).$$

Comment: It's hard to say what's gone wrong without knowing more, but of course $\frac{x + B r_0}{||x + B r_0||}$ is a unit vector in $\Bbb R^4$ and hence is in $\Bbb S^3$.

Comment: Just for the record, my numerical example is now working. MATLAB simplifications were the cause of *not getting something in* $\mathbb{S}^3$. Btw, any insight on the geometric influence of $r_0$ in this projection?

Comment: Great, glad to hear things are working. More or less by construction, $r_0$ is the image of the group identity.

Comment: For convenience, I could consider to change the metric for $\langle x, y\rangle=x^t.B.y$, where $B=\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$. This changes the way we represent an element in $\textrm{SO}^+(1, 4)$, now I would write $A=\pmatrix{\alpha & x^t & \beta \\ y & W & -y\\ \beta & -x^t & \alpha}\in\textrm{SO}(1, 4)$. I understand that also the projection would change, but my computations seem to fail. Can you help? Sorry for the continuous chain of questions, but this Lie group really intrigues me... Thanks again